# ¿Como convertir string o cadena de javascript en object json?

Tags: javascript, json

Mediante una peticion a un web service me llega este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un string o cadena de javascript y deseo convertir ese resultado a un objeto json. Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera, pero me sigue dando lo mismo:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.return));
```

Comment: Es un array de objetos JSON. Usa un índice para acceder a cada objeto individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas convirtiendo primero a `string` y luego a objeto por eso te da el mismo resultado ya que son operaciones inversas. En su lugar convierte a objeto solamente y tendrás el resultado que esperas.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.return);
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente funciono así. Le había puesto el stringify pero no recuerdo por que... algo me pasaba. Gracias @devconcept

Answer (score 1):

Te sobra la llamada a stringify.

El método stringify convierte un objeto a una cadena JSON (que es lo que ya tienes), mientras el método parse realiza la conversión inversa.

Debería bastarte con:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.return);
```